# Do C/C++ pointers save user data?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I ahve googled and searched this on stackoverflow, but the results are on how to use pointers.
Sorry if my question is nooby, i'm learning c at the time.

But do C/C++ pointers save user input during program execution since they are addressed in memory?

EDIT 2:

Do C/C++ pointers save user input after program execution?

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I understand C and C++ pointers, user input, program execution, and memory addressing. I don't understand your question. Perhaps an example of what you're asking about would help.

Comment: This question is very confused. Every variable can save user input.

Comment: This question is really unclear. Could you perhaps provide a bit of context or example code, and be clear about what you want to know?

Comment: Define "save" and "user data".

Comment: A pointer stores an address to a memory location where some value is stored (which could be yet another address)

Comment: Maybe he is asking if data written to pointers persists after the program has exited?

Comment: Data _can_ persist after program execution, but after `main` returns, the Operating system can do whatever it wants to the process memory, so I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers are just integers containing memory addresses.  Nothing more.  So a pointer itself does not save user data.  However, a pointer can point at an instance of a `class`/`struct` which can itself save user data.

Comment: Adding to this, when I was a kid, the common analogy for memory was [a pigeon-hole message box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeon-hole_messagebox). A pointer in this analogy is a message stating something like "Pigeon-hole 50". It's just another message stored in a pigeon-hole itself, except it tells you where to look to find some other message.

Comment: To stop the misconceptions before they spread: pointers aren't integers. They are addresses.

Comment: @GManNickG - The naive view is that a pointer is an address, and an address is an integer value. This breaks down because standards allow for portability to some weird platforms, including e.g. the Harvard architecture (which has different address spaces for code and data). But the best time to worry about that is *after* the naive view is understood - I don't think OP will be doing pointer arithmetic any time soon.